# Modal closed immediatly after form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, modal-dialog, submit

I'm back with my form ....

My form validation runs well so now I try to load a confirmation modal after that my form was valided and submited, so that users just click "understood".
When I click on the submit button, my modal appear and disapear immediately, I think it's because, after that the form was submited, the window is refreshed.

I spend a whole day at this f**king things and I don't be able to fix it.
I don't understand something...

My question is simple, how can I load my modal after that my form was submited ??

My JS code :

```
function editNav() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

// DOM Elements
const modalbg = document.querySelector(".bground");
const modalBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-btn");
const formData = document.querySelectorAll(".formData");

//VARIABLES
const xButton = document.querySelector(".close"); // Bouton croix
const subButton = document.querySelector(".button"); //Bouton submit

let firstName = document.querySelector("#firstName"); // Prénom
let lastName = document.querySelector("#lastName"); // Nom
let email = document.querySelector("#email"); //Email
let birthdate = document.querySelector("#birthdate"); //Date de naissance
let nbrTournaments = document.querySelector("#quantity"); //Nbr tournois
let myForm = document.getElementById("reserve");


//Formulaire complet
let emailError = document.querySelector(".mail-error"); //Erreur email
let firstNameError = document.querySelector('.firstname-error'); //Erreur prénom
let lastNameError = document.querySelector('.lastname-error'); //Erreur nom
let tournamentError = document.querySelector('.tournament-error'); //Erreur nbr tournois
let radioError = document.querySelector(".radio-button-error");//Erreur checkbox
let radioButton = document.forms[0].location;//Radio button
let birthdateError = document.querySelector(".birthdate-error");
let checkboxError = document.querySelector(".checkbox-error");
let checkbox = document.querySelector("#checkbox1");

//REGEXP
let emailRegExp = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
let dateRegExp =/^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/


//MODAL
// launch modal event
modalBtn.forEach((btn) => btn.addEventListener("click", launchModal));
// launch modal form
function launchModal() {
  modalbg.style.display = "block";
}
// close modal event
xButton.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
// close modal form
function closeModal() {
  modalbg.style.display = "none";
}
//===================================================================================

//ThanksMODAL CONST
const thanksModalContainer = document.querySelector(".thanks-modal-container"); //ThanksMODAL container
const closeThanksModalBtn = document.querySelector(".thanks-modal-close-btn");
//Modal close button
closeThanksModalBtn.addEventListener("click", closeThanksModal);
// close thanks-modal FUNCTION
function closeThanksModal() {
  thanksModalContainer.style.display = "none";
}


//launch thanks-modal EVENT
subButton.addEventListener("submit",launchThanksModal)
//launch thanks-modal FUNCTION
function launchThanksModal() {
  thanksModalContainer.style.display = "block";
}
//======================================================================================
//VALIDATION FORMULAIRE

function validate() {
  // Validation Prenom
  if (firstName.value === "") {
    firstNameError.innerHTML = "Votre prénom doit contenir 2 caractères ou plus.";
    // return false;
  }
  // Validation Nom
  if (lastName.value === "") {
    lastNameError.innerHTML = "Votre nom doit contenir 2 caractères ou plus!";
    // return false;
  }
  //Validation Mail
  let testEmail = emailRegExp.test(email.value);
  if ((testEmail === false) || (email.value === "")) {
    emailError.innerHTML = "Veuillez saisir une adresse email valide.";
    // return false;
  }
  //Validation Date de naissance
  let testDate = dateRegExp.test(birthdate.value);
  if (testDate === false) {
    birthdateError.innerHTML = "Veuillez entrer votre date de naissance.";
    // return false;
  }
  //Validation nombre de tournois
  if (nbrTournaments.value === "") {
    tournamentError.innerHTML = "Veuillez entrer un nombre";
    // return false;
  }
  //Validation Radio Button
  //Boucle vérifier
  let valid = false;
for(let i = 0; i < radioButton.length; i++) {
  if (radioButton[i].checked){
    valid = true;
    break;
  }
}
if(valid) {
  radioError.innerHTML = ""
} else {
  radioError.innerHTML = "Veuillez choisir une option";
  // return false;
}
//Validation Checkbox
  if (checkbox.checked === false) {
    checkboxError.innerHTML = "Veuillez lire et valider les conditions."
    // return false;
  }
if ((!valid||!testDate||!testEmail||!checkbox.checked)||(lastName.value === "")||(firstName.value === "")||(nbrTournaments.value === "")) {
  return false;
}
  launchThanksModal();
}
```

My HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Reservation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="modal.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=DM+Sans"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <div class="header-logo">
      <img alt="logo" src="Logo.png" width="auto" height="auto" />
    </div>
    <div class="main-navbar">
      
      <a href="#" class="active"><span>Accueil</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span>Détails de l'évènement</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span>À propos</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span>Évènements passés</span></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="editNav()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <main>
      <div class="hero-section">
        <div class="hero-content">
          <h1 class="hero-headline">
            Marathon national<br>
            de jeux vidéos
          </h1>
          <p class="hero-text">
            Vous aimez jouer ? Notre prochain évènement gaming est ouvert
            aux réservations... Places limitées !
          </p>
          <button class="btn-signup modal-btn">
            je m'inscris
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="hero-img">
          <img src="./bg_img.jpg" alt="img" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn-signup modal-btn">
          je m'inscris
        </button>
      </div>
<!--MODAL-->
      <div class="bground">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close"></span>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form
              id="reserve"
              name="reserve"
              action="index.html"
              method="get"
              onsubmit="return validate();"
            >
              <div
                class="formData">
                <label for="firstName">Prénom</label><br>
                <input
                  class="text-control"
                  type="text"
                  id="firstName"
                  name="firstName"
                  minlength="2"
                /><br>
                <span class="firstname-error errormsg"></span>
              </div>
              <div
                class="formData">
                <label for="lastName">Nom</label><br>
                <input
                  class="text-control"
                  type="text"
                  id="lastName"
                  name="lastName"
                /><br>
                <span class="lastname-error errormsg"></span>
              </div>
              <div
                class="formData">
                <label for="email">Email</label><br>
                <input
                  class="text-control"
                  type="email"
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                /><br>
                <span class="mail-error errormsg"></span>
              </div>
              <div
                class="formData">
                <label for="birthdate">Date de naissance</label><br>
                <input
                  class="text-control"
                  type="date"
                  id="birthdate"
                  name="birthdate"
                /><br>
                <span class="birthdate-error errormsg"></span>
              </div>
              <div
                class="formData">
                <label for="quantity">À combien de tournois GameOn avez-vous déjà participé ?</label><br>

                <input type="number" class="text-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="0" max="99"><br>
                <span class="tournament-error errormsg"></span>
              </div>
              <p class="text-label">A quel tournoi souhaitez-vous participer cette année ?</p>
              <div
                class="formData">
                <input
                  class="checkbox-input"
                  type="radio"
                  id="location1"
                  name="location"
                  value="New York"
                />
                <label class="checkbox-label" for="location1">
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  New York</label
                >
                <input
                  class="checkbox-input"
                  type="radio"
                  id="location2"
                  name="location"
                  value="San Francisco"
                />
                <label class="checkbox-label" for="location2">
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  San Francisco</label
                >
                <input
                  class="checkbox-input"
                  type="radio"
                  id="location3"
                  name="location"
                  value="Seattle"
                />
                <label class="checkbox-label" for="location3">
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  Seattle</label
                >
                <input
                  class="checkbox-input"
                  type="radio"
                  id="location4"
                  name="location"
                  value="Chicago"
                />
                <label class="checkbox-label" for="location4">
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  Chicago</label
                >
                <input
                  class="checkbox-input"
                  type="radio"
                  id="location5"
                  name="location"
                  value="Boston"
                />
                <label class="checkbox-label" for="location5">
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  Boston</label
                >
                <input
                  class="checkbox-input"
                  type="radio"
                  id="location6"
                  name="location"
                  value="Portland"
                />
                <label class="checkbox-label" for="location6">
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  Portland</label
                >
              </div>
              <span class="radio-button-error errormsg"></span>
              <div
                class="formData">
                <input
                  class="checkbox-input"
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="checkbox1"
                  checked
                />
                <label class="checkbox2-label" for="checkbox1" required>
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  J'ai lu et accepté les conditions d'utilisation.
                </label><p class="checkbox-error errormsg"></p>
                <input class="checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" />
                <label class="checkbox2-label" for="checkbox2">
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  Je Je souhaite être prévenu des prochains évènements.
                </label>
                <br>
              </div>
              <input
                class="btn-submit"
                type="submit"
                class="button"
                value="C'est parti"
              />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<!--      FIN MODAL-->
<!--      MODAL CONFIRMATION ENVOI-->
      <div class="thanks-modal-container">
        <div class="overlay modal-triggers"></div>
          <div class="thanks-modal-content">
            <p class="thanks-modal-text">Merci, votre réservation a bien été prise en compte</p>
            <button class="thanks-modal-close-btn">OK</button>
          </div>
      </div>
<!--    FIN MODAL CONFIRMATION ENVOI-->
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p class="copyrights">
        Copyright 2014 - 2022, GameOn Inc.
      </p>
    </footer>
    <script src="modal.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Sending a form means navigating to its `action` URL. This will load that URL, i.e. remove any modals, open or not. You need to decide whether the form is sent directly (in which case you need to redirect to a thank you page on the server) or whether you stop the submission event and send the form data via ajax, this way you'll stay on the page and can show the modal.

Comment: The form's action is "index.html", which will basically just reload the page I guess. Do you have an actual backend to process the form data?

Answer (score 2):

You need **event.preventDefault()** on form submission so it does not reload the page, and handle your submission logic with only js. Use something like this:

```
<form onsubmit="submitForm(event)">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
  function submitForm(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // your custom submission logic
    // display modal on success
  }
</script>
```

Comment: While this is true for a form where the data is submitted using ajax/fetch, this doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Yes, but if it is not submitted with ajax page will always reload, so it is required to display modal without page reloading.

Comment: Yes, but until OP explains, we can't answer this properly. And linking to a dupe is also not an answer, you should flag it as dupe instead (if you're sure it's a dupe)

Comment: Not a dupe i think, as question is about modal, but still i agree with you, i will remove link.

Comment: Thank you all !
At this time, my modal opened when my form is valid but I think because of the preventDefaut nothings happen next.
When I close the modal, my form is still here, wainting...., with the inputs full filled.
For infos, this is an exercice, my form is sending infos nowhere, there is no backend of course !